# How to pass password to decode LZMA (7zip) encrypted archive in C / Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, 7zip, lzma

Does anyone know how to pass password to decode function in LZMA SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sources and another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221049/how-secure-is-7-zip), I'm guessing it will be good to start looking at where and how the sha256* functions are defined and used.  The documentation appears minimal to nothing, so the code should be your major guide along with your knowledge of cryptography.